# Getting the static file from filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io

Filepicker.io seems to always return files with `Content-Disposition: attachment; ..` which is causing it to download or throw a save as dialog.

How can I get the file without this header? I would like users to just be able to open the image in their browser.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `?dl=false` flag.

https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/hFHUCB3iTxyMzseuWOgG?dl=false